# getting authorization code from url

Tags: c#, oauth

When using oauth I can get an authorization code returned in the URL to me but i don't know how to get that code out of the url. For example when i give the app permission to run i get

```
http://localhost/?code=moBOuHmeCj.KUjTq14iwVyywiLbB44SNZ4-olDb2uFmXOwPpFzV.PQUHfFCNKAqStMp8.NMDZPjEZMJosDMC0JKZip.qHTvQ5KHI9oFIGwNh79EabwklUQjVgXzrc4Mor6mcmMRVTJTos3mv2BzIEw%3D%3D
```

as a response but i need to get that out of the browser and back to the server to get the long access key.How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set your authentication provider's returnUrl as a specific route of your site, something like `http://localhost/oauth`

In your OAuthController (I'm assuming your question is about a MVC app) use:

```
public ActionResult Index(string code)
{
    // Perform any action related with 'code' value provided by auth provider.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```